Why is LLMChain's answer being cut off?
I want to build a question-answering application using the Huggingface API with the Gemma model, but the answer provided by the model is being cut off. I've tried it on Google Colab and Kaggle notebooks, and it always gets cut off. What could be the reason for this?
This is my code below;
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from langchain_community.llms import HuggingFaceHub
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate

//Loaded api key
load_dotenv()
//Models name
hub_llm = HuggingFaceHub(repo_id="google/gemma-1.1-7b-it")

prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["text-generation"],
    template="Text generation :{text-generation}"
    )

hub_chain = LLMChain(prompt=prompt,llm =hub_llm,verbose=True)
print(hub_chain.run("How does the brain work ? "))

And the output seems like that: 
Also tried in kaggle/colab notebooks: 
What should I do ?

I solved the problem by changing this code:
hub_llm = HuggingFaceHub(repo_id="google/gemma-1.1-7b-it") 

to include model_kwargs:
hub_llm = HuggingFaceHub(
    repo_id="google/gemma-1.1-7b-it",
    model_kwargs={"temperature": 0.8, "max_new_tokens": 2000},
)

